# Create my own mapping for XeTeX fonts

Tags: fonts, symbols, xetex, plain-tex

I'm trying to create mapping files, to make use of Cambria Math italic calligraphic and double stroke letters in Plain XeTeX. However, I'm unable to do so. This is what I tried to create for the italic mapping based on tex-text.map:

```
; Math italic conversion for Cambria Math (and the like)

LHSName "Math-Italic"
RHSName "UNICODE"

[...]    

pass(Unicode)

; Latin big and SMALL letters
U+0041   <> U+1D434 ; A
U+0042   <> U+1D435 ; B
U+0043   <> U+1D436 ; C
U+0044   <> U+1D437 ; D
U+0045   <> U+1D438 ; E
U+0046   <> U+1D434 ; F
U+0047   <> U+1D439 ; G
U+0048   <> U+1D43A ; H
U+0049   <> U+1D43B ; I
U+004A   <> U+1D43C ; J
U+004B   <> U+1D43D ; K
U+004C   <> U+1D43E ; L
U+004D   <> U+1D43F ; M
U+004E   <> U+1D440 ; N
U+004F   <> U+1D441 ; O
U+0050   <> U+1D442 ; P
U+0051   <> U+1D443 ; Q
U+0052   <> U+1D444 ; R
U+0053   <> U+1D445 ; S
U+0054   <> U+1D446 ; T
U+0055   <> U+1D447 ; U
U+0056   <> U+1D448 ; V
U+0057   <> U+1D44A ; W
U+0058   <> U+1D44B ; X
U+0059   <> U+1D44C ; Y
U+005A   <> U+1D44D ; Z

U+0061   <> U+1D44E ; a
U+0062   <> U+1D44F ; b
U+0063   <> U+1D450 ; c
U+0064   <> U+1D451 ; d
U+0065   <> U+1D452 ; e
U+0066   <> U+1D453 ; f
U+0067   <> U+1D454 ; g
U+0068   <> U+210E  ; h
U+0069   <> U+1D456 ; i
U+006A   <> U+1D457 ; j
U+006B   <> U+1D458 ; k
U+006C   <> U+1D459 ; l
U+006D   <> U+1D45A ; m
U+006E   <> U+1D45B ; n
U+006F   <> U+1D45C ; o
U+0070   <> U+1D45D ; p
U+0071   <> U+1D45E ; q
U+0072   <> U+1D45F ; r
U+0073   <> U+1D460 ; s
U+0074   <> U+1D461 ; t
U+0075   <> U+1D462 ; u
U+0076   <> U+1D463 ; v
U+0077   <> U+1D464 ; w
U+0078   <> U+1D465 ; x
U+0079   <> U+1D466 ; y
U+007A   <> U+1D467 ; z

; Greek big and SMALL letters

;đť›ł
U+0391   <> U+1D6E2 ; Alpha
U+0392   <> U+1D6E3 ; Betha
U+0393   <> U+1D6E4 ; Gamma
U+0394   <> U+1D6E5 ; Delta
U+0395   <> U+1D6E6 ; Epsilon
U+0396   <> U+1D6E7 ; Zeta
U+0397   <> U+1D6E8 ; Eta
U+0398   <> U+1D6E9 ; Theta
U+0399   <> U+1D6EA ; Iota
U+039A   <> U+1D6EB ; Kappa
U+039B   <> U+1D6EC ; Lambda
U+039C   <> U+1D6ED ; Mu
U+039D   <> U+1D6EE ; Nu
U+039E   <> U+1D6EF ; Xi
U+039F   <> U+1D6F0 ; Omicron
U+03A0   <> U+1D6F1 ; Pi
U+03A1   <> U+1D6F2 ; Ro
U+03A3   <> U+1D6F4 ; Sigma
U+03A4   <> U+1D6F5 ; Tau
U+03A5   <> U+1D6F6 ; Upsilon
U+03A6   <> U+1D6F7 ; Phi
U+03A7   <> U+1D6F8 ; Chi
U+03A8   <> U+1D6F9 ; Psi
U+03A9   <> U+1D6FA ; Omega

U+03B1   <> U+1D6FC ; alpha
U+03B2   <> U+1D6FD ; betha
U+03B3   <> U+1D6FE ; gamma
U+03B4   <> U+1D6FF ; delta
U+03B5   <> U+1D600 ; varepsilon
U+03B6   <> U+1D701 ; zeta
U+03B7   <> U+1D702 ; eta
U+03B8   <> U+1D703 ; theta
U+03B9   <> U+1D704 ; iota
U+03BA   <> U+1D705 ; kappa
U+03BB   <> U+1D706 ; lambda
U+03BC   <> U+1D707 ; mu
U+03BD   <> U+1D708 ; nu
U+03BE   <> U+1D709 ; xi
U+03BF   <> U+1D70A ; omicron
U+03C0   <> U+1D70B ; pi
U+03C1   <> U+1D70C ; ro
U+03C3   <> U+1D70D ; varsigma
U+03C3   <> U+1D70E ; sigma
U+03C4   <> U+1D70F ; tau
U+03C5   <> U+1D710 ; upsilon
U+03C6   <> U+1D711 ; phi
U+03C7   <> U+1D712 ; chi
U+03C8   <> U+1D713 ; psi
U+03C9   <> U+1D714 ; omega
U+03F5   <> U+1D715 ; epsilon
U+03D1   <> U+1D717 ; vartheta
U+03F0   <> U+1D718 ; varkappa
U+03D5   <> U+1D719 ; varphi
U+03F1   <> U+1D71A ; varrho
U+03D6   <> U+1D71B ; varpi
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You could use [unicode-math](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) and just set the math font to Cambria Math.

Comment: I cannot use this, since it is a LaTeX package. (Or there is only documentation for LaTeX.) I'm using Plain XeTeX

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured what I did wrong. First, I don't needed the part that is currently marked with [...], and I only need the `>` conversion instead of `<>`.

But most important, that map files does not used directly, I need to convert it to a `*.tec˙` file. But that itself is not enough, it is need to be placed under `texmf/fonts/misc/xetex/fontmapping`. You may need to copy the map file as well, I didn't tried it without that yet. Conversion is done with TECkit.

However, the TECkit converter is not shipped with MiKTeX (or maybe not even with TeX Live), so you need to download that from [TECkit Download page](http://intranet.ipub.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?&item_id=TECkitDownloads).

The command that you need to use:

```
teckit_compile <file>.map -o <file>.tec
```

If this does not work (since this isn't what I used as my last attempt) or it is not satisfying for you, you may alternatively use the SILConverters, that you can download from [SILConverters page Download section](http://intranet.ipub.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=EncCnvtrs#c20c35ef), that is also can show you what characters will be translated to what characters, but that is only available for Windows. (I needed to copy the DLL files from the first downloaded file to the programs folder, so it is possible that is the same because of this.)

Don't forget to refresh the File Name database. You can do that with `texhash`.

Comment: Good summary of the necessary steps. Sorry I couldn't help here, I did write such files for myself once, but I lost them through poor data management :-(  (and I've long since forgotten the exact process)

Comment: That's okay. Where would be the fun if I get the answer in the first place, and could not figure it out by my self? ;-)
(I know, that I also will forget this, but I know then where to look for it.)

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but I think you are doing it the wrong way. You should use `\XeTeXmathchardef` and the likes instead, something like:

```
\XeTeXmathchardef\alpha = "1 "1 "1D6FC
```

Check [XeTeX Reference](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/xetexref/XeTeX-reference.pdf) for syntax.

Comment: That was not my point. I've just refined my question, to clearly see, what I actually want. Actually that was only an experiment part of my code.

Comment: You have `\XeTeXmathcode`.

Comment: I believe that would do the trick, but that can't be binded to a font. For instance, I may want a part of math to be displayed in normal roman, or double stroke characters. That would require me to redefine each letter each time I want to switch the font.

Comment: Well, how plain TeX does it then?