# Real number symbol (UTF-8: ℝ) in XeTeX

Tags: math-mode, xetex, symbols, amsmath, plain-tex

How can I get the 'real number' sign (something like `\mathbb{R}` with the amssymb package in LaTeX) in XeTeX?

Comment: Can you add the essential part of your preamble, particularly the font setting?

Comment: well I have no preamble since I'm on XeTeX ;-)

Comment: @ivaneesbeeck, i don't understand your answer.

Comment: The preamble is what goes from `\documentclass` to `\begin{document}`. If you plan to use `amssymb` you *must* have this.

Comment: XeTeX is an extension of TeX designed to work with unicode encoding. Just as for (plain) TeX, it has no preamble in its documents

Comment: @egreg He’s not planning to use `amssymb`, he only wants the `\mathbb{R}` sign in XeTeX.

Comment: @Ivaneesbeeck Please add the username in your comment to respond properly (as I did here), otherwise the person will not be notified of your message. It would still be interesting to see your font setup. `\font\1="Linux Libertine O"\1 ℝ\bye` works great for me.

Comment: I see; nothing prevents you from using the `msbm10` font with XeTeX. In any case, if you don't set fonts, you're basically using the same setting as normal TeX.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @Jubobs Yes right! I wanted to accept my answer but it said I musted wait 2 days to do it. Time going, I forgot this thread. Thigs are fixed now!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Auto-answer:

```
\input amssym.tex
${\Bbb R}$
\bye
```

works fine

Comment: Did you mean `\input amssymb.tex`?

Comment: @Jubobs Nope, amssym. On my computer this code snippet does the job

Answer (score 203):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Plain-\TeX{}:   & ${\rm I\!R}$\\
amssymb:        & $\mathbb{R}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Neither of these options produce a U+211D character in the output.

Comment: @TylerCrompton You need special packages to generate Unicode characters in the output: [xetex - What is the difference between unicode-math and mathspec? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118244/what-is-the-difference-between-unicode-math-and-mathspec?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 15):

You should put your symbol format definitions in another TeX file; publications tend to have their own styles, and some may use bold Roman for fields like **R** instead of blackboard bold.  You can swap `nams.tex` with `aom.tex`.  I know, this is more common with LaTeX, but the principle still applies.

For example:

```
% paper.tex
\input nams.tex
$\realnumbers$ is connected.

% nams.tex
\def\realnumbers{\mathbb{R}}
% more definitions for the Notices.

% aom.tex
\def\realnumbers{\mathbf{R}}
% more definitions for the Annals.
```

Just change one line in paper.tex to submit to the Annals instead of the Notices.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). May be an example/illustration would help to support the answer.

Answer (score 12):

With `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
$ℝ$
\end{document}
```

[image: real symbol]

Comment: That also works in XeLaTeX.  So does `$\mathbb{R}$`.

Answer (score 8):

There's a couple of ways to go about this:

1. Using the default **Computer Modern** -font (which, as you've already found out, can be extended with the `amssym` to have access to BlackBoardBold.)
2. Using **Unicode OpenType** math fonts. Now this is a bit tricky because the glyph locations  need to be (re-)told to TeX. This step can further be split into two different approaches:

   1. Use just **one family** and change the active range by re-telling TeX the glyph positions every time the style changes (i.e. script, fraktur, etc. This is the way I've understood the `unicode-math` -package does it). For plain-xetex, you could do something along [these lines](https://gist.github.com/morbusg/9388664).
   2. Fix the styles to their own `\fam`ilies using **mapping-files** created with `teckit_compile` from [SIL](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?cat_id=teckit). See: [Changing math font to OTF in XeTeX using plaintex-format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3901/1410).