# What is the difference between unicode-math and mathspec?

Tags: xetex, best-practices, unicode-math, mathspec

I'm currently typesetting my lecture notes for classical electrodynamics using the `tufte-book` class and XeLaTeX.

This is my first time using XeLaTeX and so I stumbled upon the two packages `unicode-math` and `mathspec`, when it came to include an OpenType math font (here TeX Gyre Pagelle Math).

I browsed the documentation of the two packages a little bit, but wasn't able to find out, which is the "better practice" to use.

**Question:** Should I use `unicode-math` or `mathspec` for my XeLaTeX documents?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

(Please note that this answer has been revised to reflect issues raised in the comments.)

### unicode-math

The `unicode-math` and `mathspec` packages have very different goals. The `unicode-math` package is designed to map math markup into unicode characters as supplied by real OpenType math fonts such as the Latin Modern Math,  STIX, Asana Math.  It also allows (as much as makes sense/is possible) Unicode *input* of math, as well as output so that you can enter unicode math characters in the source and have them be interpreted correctly as math by TeX.

For example, you could create the following document:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

This is some math text entered with math in the source:
\[
∀X [ ∅ ∉ X ⇒ ∃f:X ⟶  ⋃ X\ ∀A ∈ X (f(A) ∈ A ) ]\]

This is some math text entered with regular markup

\[
\forall X [\emptyset \not\in X \Rightarrow \exists f:X \rightarrow  \bigcup X\ 
    \forall A \in X (f(A) \in A ) ]\]
\end{document}
```

which would produce

[image: output of unicode-math]

The `unicode-math` package is compatible with both XeTeX and LuaTeX.

### mathspec

The `mathspec` package is not designed to allow you to use unicode characters in your source math input. Instead it is designed to allow you to use open-type fonts within math so that you can, for example, match the text font of your math with the text font in your document.

So for example you can use:

```
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setmathfont(Digits,Latin)[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Libertine O}


\begin{document}
This is some text in Libertine \emph{X(f(A))}
\[
\forall X [\emptyset \not\in X \Rightarrow \exists f:X \rightarrow  \bigcup X\ 
    \forall A \in X (f(A) \in A ) ]\]
\end{document}
```

which will produce:

[image: mathspec output]

The `mathspec` package can only be used with XeTeX; it cannot be used with LuaTeX.

### Which should you use

If you want to use one of the available OpenType math fonts, then using `unicode-math` makes sense.

If you want to match a non-math font with the math font then `mathspec` can help, but because TeX does not apply kerning between characters from different fonts, using `mathspec` has its drawbacks, since you may find places in which the switch from the text font to the math font produces bad spacing, as in the example given.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! What does the empty `\setmathfont{}` do? I read something about `mathspec` being XeTeX only, while `unicode-math` also supports LuaLaTeX; is that true? I think having portable documents is always better.

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, that's true.  `mathspec` is not compatible with LuaTeX. (The extra `\setmathfont` was a typo).

Comment: (+1) You could use  ⋃ (U+22C3) instead of \bigcup to have an a no-markup example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks.  I've fixed the example, but it reinforces the point about how painful it can be to enter unicode source: I was didn't immediately find that character with my character viewer; also in the source the n-ary union is almost indistinguishable from the regular union character, which is kind of defeats the purpose of having more readable input.

Comment: some niggly differences between examples: first `\in` not negated in libertine; "slash-space" before `\forall` not observed in libertine; spacing around colons not the same (different unicode?); spacing/kerning around final `f` in libertine is terrible.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, I was going to the kerning issue.  (The lack of negation is a typo; I'd not noticed the space issue.) The kerning issues (as you know) are due to the fact that TeX doesn't apply kerning between characters from different fonts, and the parentheses are not from libertine, I think. This is certainly one of the potential downsides of the `mathspec` package unless you're using a complete unicode math font like STIX or Asana Math, Cambria Math, etc.

Comment: @AlanMunn There is no need to use Unicode input with `unicode-math`; it works perfectly with traditional input.

Comment: I don’t think the description of `unicode-math` is right, the Unicode input is merely a side effect of the main goal; supporting Unicode math *fonts*, and you can still use csnames for math inout, which is actually what most people do.

Comment: @KhaledHosny Thank you Khaled and egreg.  I've edited the answer in light of your comments.

Comment: The only kind-of-usable Unicode source input method that I know is Agda's input method — which accepts LaTeX names *and* also some shortenings

Answer (score 53):

`mathspec` is a clever attempt to make it possible to use math in XeLaTeX documents, with system fonts for the letters and symbols from standard math fonts.

With `unicode-math` one can basically use only specially tailored OpenType math fonts such as Latin Modern Math, TeX Gyre Termes Math, TeX Gyre Pagella Math, XITS Math, Asana Math (among the free ones) or Cambria Math and Lucida Bright Math (not free).

### `mathspec`

With this package you can do limited math with the main system font. Just a silly example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Old Standard}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){Old Standard}
\begin{document}
Some text and a formula $a+b=\int_{\xi}^{\theta} f(x)\,dx$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The emulated math is not bad, and the package has features for manually correcting the possible bad spacings, which happen because the fonts have really no support for math. For instance, inputting the formula as

```
$a+b=\int_{\xi}^{\theta} "f(x)\,dx$
```

would give the better result

[image]

The `"` means ”add some space on both sides of the following letter”.

Digits, Latin and Greek letters can be taken from different fonts.

### `unicode-math`

The `unicode-math` is compatible both with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. Here's the same example with Lucida Bright:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=0.85]{Lucida Bright OT}
\setmathfont[Scale=0.85]{Lucida Bright Math OT}
\begin{document}
Some text and a formula $a+b=\int_{\xi}^{\theta} f(x)\,dx$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Spacing is correct without manual intervention, because the font used for math is a *real* math font. Here's the same with TeX Gyre Pagella:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\begin{document}
Some text and a formula $a+b=\int_{\xi}^{\theta} f(x)\,dx$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Unicode input

One *can* input math with Unicode symbols, but this is not mandatory. It's possible both with `mathspec` and `unicode-math`. For instance, the integral with `mathspec` could be input as

```
$∫_ξ^θ "f(x)\,dx$
```

provided that `∫` is made known to the environment, for instance with

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{∫}{\int}
```

Some symbols (in particular letters) are already known.

Nothing particular is needed for inputting the integral as

```
$∫_ξ^θ f(x)\,dx$
```

with `unicode-math`. However the traditional syntax is understood by the package.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! It is very helpful to know, how to define additional unicode symbols as math operators.

Comment: I would not call it 'clever' tbh. that's a standard feature of some programming language. to not have it by default in a language dedicated to typesetting is laughable

Comment: @egreg Is it possible to somehow use sequences of unicode symbols without having to load `unicode-math`? I am thinking in particular about mapping `⁻¹` to `^{-1}`.

Comment: @Gaussler It *may* be possible; whether it's convenient is another matter

Comment: Is it better to use TeX-Gyre Pagella Math, NewPX, Neo-Euler or Asana?.  I'm looking for some opentype font with nice math, and with text looking like Palatino (because of university restrictions).

Comment: These examples didn't load explicitly `fontspec` package but use `\setmainfont` macro from this package. Does it mean that `unicode-math` and `mathspec` packages load `fontspec` by default? Is so what fonts are loaded as the main, sans-serif and monospace fonts?

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov Both packages are indeed based on fontspec and they load it. The default fonts are from the Larin Modern family of typefaces.

Comment: suppressing my comments because already pointed out by more authoritative bb [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available/425099?noredirect=1#comment1063766_425098)

Comment: The list of OpenType math fonts has increased since the answer has been written.

Answer (score 33):

`unicode-math` is mainly concerned about facilitating the use of using Unicode math fonts, namely OpenType math fonts in LaTeX. While `mathspec` is about allowing to take math alphabets from text fonts in the absence of matching math font.

Unicode defines a large set of math symbols and many fonts include them, but proper math typesetting requires many font parameters to aid the typesetting engine and those have to be provided by the font. Traditionally TeX fonts would provide the needed parameters in the font dimension of TFM files, which meant that non-TFM fonts can not be used to typeset math in XeTeX (and later LuaTeX). When Microsoft started adding TeX-like math typesetting in Word, they extended OpenType with a special `MATH` table to hold the needed parameters for math typesetting and XeTeX implemented it (and later LuaTeX) and `unicode-math` was written to provide macro support for using the new fonts. So with `unicode-math` you get proper math typesetting with proper OpenType math fonts, like TeX Gyre Pagelle Math, but you are limited to those specially prepared fonts.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I like espacially, that you provided additional information on the history.

Comment: So the reason that using `mathspec` leads to the differences shown in the other answers is that it tries to be compatible to *any* font that defines the Unicode math characters, not only those that provide the additional parameters you mentioned? Put differently, it will ignore those parameters even if they are available?

Comment: @balu The fonts don't necessarily need to define the unicode maths characters. `mathspec` lets you use just e.g. the letters for a calligraphic alphabet or the letters from your text font for operator and variable names etc. so that text and maths use the same ABC ... abc ... or whatever. You can substitute just the bits you want - pick 'n mix.