# "+-=,;..." math characters in DejaVu Sans (with mathspec)

Tags: xetex

the following MWE

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){DejaVu Sans}
\setmathrm{DejaVu Sans}
\begin{document}
\(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi}=-1\) = -1
\end{document}
```

typesets with xelatex into

[image]

How can I turn the = and - signs in math mode to DejaVu Sans ?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 2):

You can use “standard” declarations (note that in the formula I used the ASCII hyphen, outside it the minus sign U+2212).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){DejaVu Sans}
\setmathrm{DejaVu Sans}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSymbol{=}{\mathrel}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`=}
\DeclareMathSymbol{+}{\mathbin}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`+}
\XeTeXDeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathbin}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{"2212}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi}=-1+1-1\) = −1+1−1

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also add

```
\XeTeXDeclareMathSymbol{^^^^2212}{\mathbin}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{"2212}
```

for completeness.

More complete version (with also `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){DejaVu Sans}
\setmathrm{DejaVu Sans}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSymbol{=}{\mathrel}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`=}
\DeclareMathSymbol{+}{\mathbin}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`+}
\DeclareMathSymbol{.}{\mathord}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`.}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ldotp}{\mathpunct}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`.}
\DeclareMathSymbol{;}{\mathpunct}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`;}
\DeclareMathSymbol{,}{\mathpunct}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{`,}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cdot}{\mathbin}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{"00B7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cdotp}{\mathpunct}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{"00B7}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \XeTeXDeclareMathSymbol{-}{\mathbin}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{"2212}%
  \XeTeXDeclareMathSymbol{^^^^2212}{\mathbin}{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}{"2212}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi}=−1+1−1\) = −1+1−1

\(;.,\ldots\cdots\)

\(,\dots,\) \(a+\dots+z\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek){DejaVu Sans}
\setmathrm{DejaVu Sans}
% 0 (large) \mathop, 1 (binary) \mathbin, 2 (vary) \mathbin, 3 (relation) \mathrel, 4 (opening) \mathopen, 5 (closing) \mathclose, 6 (punctuation) \mathpunct, 7 (alphabetic) \mathalpha
\Umathcode`=="3 \csname symLatin:m:n\endcsname `=
\Umathcode`-="2 \csname symLatin:m:n\endcsname `-
\Umathcode`×="2 \csname symLatin:m:n\endcsname `× \def\times{×}
\begin{document}
\(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\pi}=-1\) = -1
\end{document}
```

giving

[image: hyphen from font]

as requested.

However, note that `-` is `U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS` and there is also `−` `U+2212 MINUS SIGN`, which you might want to use instead:

[image: minus sign from font]

For this, replace the relevant line by

```
\Umathcode`-="2 \csname symLatin:m:n\endcsname `−
```

(last character in line being `U+2212 MINUS SIGN`).

I learned this from [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220831/28115) to my question [Symbols in XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220812/28115).