# Combination of \oplus and \otimes?

Tags: symbols

I've searched the usual places (http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf, http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf, DeTeXify) and can't seem to find this character, which surprises me.  I'd like a combination of `\oplus` and `\otimes`.  More precisely, I'd like a circle subdivided into eight 45° sectors.  (Sort of like `\circledast` but with the arms of the asterisk extending all the way out to the edge of the circle.)

Does such a symbol exist?  If not, how can I create one?

Comment: what does this symbol mean?  if it is generally "accepted", it should be a candidate for unicode, and i am in a position to submit it, if adequate documentation can be provided.  (some of the history of the project is given in [How many LaTeX characters have Unicode equivalents, and which characters and mathematical character combinations cannot be represented by Unicode?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227093/579) though that is not a duplicate of this question.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton it does not have a generally accepted meaning so probably should not be included in Unicode. My own use of it is idiosyncratic -- but FWIW, I want to use it in some elementary group theory notes to denote a binary operator without biasing the notation towards either multiplicative intuitions or additive ones.

Comment: As mentioned in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355070/5764), this is in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) as `\BPwheel` from [`linearb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/linearb).

Answer (score 10):

Easy `\ooalign`. `;-)` See [\subseteq + \circ as a single symbol ("open subset")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22371/subseteq-circ-as-a-single-symbol-open-subset) for a quick course on it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\oplustimes}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\o@plus@times\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\o@plus@times}[2]{%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\oplus$\cr$\m@th#1\otimes$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$X\oplustimes Y_{a\oplustimes b}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for not having forgotten, this time, the style argument… :o)

Comment: I think the symbol should be called, simply, `\pizzapie`.

Answer (score 8):

@Egreg did a great job reinventing the wheel ;-).   An alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{linearb}

\newcommand{\ugh}{\mathbin{\textlinb{\BPwheel}}}
\newcommand{\sugh}{\mathbin{\textlinb{\scriptsize\BPwheel}}}

\begin{document}

$X \ugh Y_{a \sugh b}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is in the comprehensive latex symbols list......

Comment: +1. You forgot to make `\ugh` be of type `\mathbin`, though. ;-)