# UTF-8 characters in math mode

Tags: math-mode, xetex, unicode

I'm new to this forum and to LaTeX. It's the first time I use use it and I really like it. I have a problem with it, though, I have looked for solution on this forum but I haven't found anything (or I don't know how to use other solutions for my case).

I'm using XeLateX with the editor Texpad for Mac OS X and I can't use UTF-8 characters in math mode. I've read here that I shouldn't use babel, nor inputenc, but polyglossia instead. I'm doing it and even though I have Spanish UTF-8 characters in normal mode, I don't have them on math mode. Let's see some code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\begin{document}
Algo de texto y una fórmula $á+b=\int_{\xi}^{\theta} f(x)\,dx$.
\end{document}
```

Which outputs:

[image: Code output]

As you can see, "ó" is working outside math mode but "á" isn't working in it. Maybe I should use some package such as mathspec or unicode-math, but I don't really know how.

Help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: A simple workaround would be to use `\textsf{á}` or `\textit{á}` in math mode (or even `\textit{\textsf{á}}`).  The problem is that you would not want the reader to confuse the accent for a derivative.

Comment: It's not specific to your question but maybe have a read of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118244/28808 and see if anything helps

Comment: Your example, when compiled here, doesn't give the sans-serif maths in your image - -but it does drop the "á".

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers, I will take a look to it, Chris H :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accents in math mode have to be added in a different way than in text mode; in general, an accented letter in math has no connection with the corresponding meaning in text, so *ü* in math is the second derivative of *u*, not “u with diaeresis”.

You can, if you really want to use accented letters in math, add a meaning for them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareMathUnicode}{mm}
 {
  \cs_new_protected:cpn { mathutf_#1: } { #2 }
  \char_set_active_eq:Nc #1 { mathutf_#1: }
  \char_set_mathcode:nn { `#1 } { "8000 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \char_set_active_eq:NN { Nc }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareMathUnicode{á}{\acute{a}}
% other needed declarations

\begin{document}
Algo de texto y una fórmula $á+b=\int_{\xi}^{\theta} f(x)\,dx$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! In fact, this seems to work. In fact, what I want to write is "señal", which means "signal". I think I can add this to your answer:

\DeclareMathUnicode{ñ}{\acute{n}

And it will work. 

Very interesting answer, still a lot to learn about LaTex. Thank you again :)

Comment: @lyurealm In that case you want either `\textit{señal}` or `\textrm{señal}`.

Comment: Remember that you can mark answers as "accepted" if they solved your problem :-)

Comment: While this method works, in most cases there's a simpler solution of using a package that already did the work (unicode-math, ucs, or inputenc -- I haven't looked into them)

Answer (score 2):

you can try `\mathit`:

```
Algo de texto y una fórmula $\mathit{á}+b=\int_{\xi}^{\theta} f(x)\,dx$.
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't make it work. Do I need to use some package for mathit?

Comment: did you run `xelatex` or `lualatex`

Comment: Editor says it's using XeLateX, but now you made me doubt... how can I check it?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I didn't get any error, but it didn't show neither. Kinda weird.
I've solved it using \textit{}.
Thank you very much for your help!