# How to write non-english characters in the math mode?

Tags: math-mode, extended-characters

I'd like to have the Danish letter ø in my text. It's very simple when I mean plain text: *{\o}*. How can I achieve the same result in the math mode?  If I add *{\o}* to my formulas, this character isn't printed.

I believe that my question isn't a dupplicate of any of these: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65599/utf-8-characters-in-latex-math-mode) or [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270154/utf-8-characters-in-math-mode), because I don't want to be able to write *ø* in the math mode. On the contrary, I'd like to use the command *{\o}* as I do in the text mode (it is more convenient for me since I'm not used to the Danish keyboard).

Comment: Exactly what do you need ø for in math? If it is as an index, use `R_{\textup{sø}}` or similar. ø (and `\o`)is generally not allowed in math mode.

Comment: @daleif, as an index. Thank you, it works:)

Comment: I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally non-ascii letters are not allowed in math mode, there are various methods to allow them, but generally non-english letters are only used in two cases within math

1. As a part of an index. Here it is recommended to use `_{\textup{sø}}` or `_{\textnormal{sø}}` as this switches back to the (upright) text font where non-english letters are allowed
2. The other is textual comments in a displayed formula. Here `\text{....}` is recommended.

   ```
   \[ f(x)>0 \qquad \text{for all $x>0$} \]
   ```

   as this also switch to the context correct font.

Note that it is **not** recommended to use `\text` for 1. as textual indices should be upright and `\text{text}` will be italic in an italic context.

Note this shortcut (due to @egreg)

```
\newcommand\tsub[1]{_{\textup{#1}}}
```

Then use `$R\tsub{sø}$` a bit faster to write, and also easier to change if you later on want to change `\textup` into `\textnormal`