# Does one need extra files for an OpenType font to work with luatex?

Tags: fonts, luatex, unicode-math, opentype

Suppose I want to use (with `lualatex`) an OpenType font that has no TeX support (yet). Do I need `.map`, `.enc`, `.fd`, `.tfm`, `.vf` files and/or some adjustments at LaTeX level or will `fontspec` be powerful enough to extract all the information needed from the `.otf` file and convert them to something that LaTeX would understand (NFSS?) ?

How does the answers to the preceding question apply for an OpenType **math** font loaded *via* `unicode-math`?

Comment: No, you don't need extra files.  The `.otf` contains all the information that is necessary.  For math fonts this also holds true, but to use it in a sensible way it has to contain the MATH table.

Comment: Loosely related: [What is the difference between unicode-math and mathspec?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118244/10995)

Comment: @HenriMenke What is the MATH table and how does the 'mapping'(?) works?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need map, enc, tfm, vf. xetex has the necessary code to extract the information built-in, for luatex you need a fontloader like e.g. luaotfload.

You normally also don't need fd-files. fontspec tries hard to guess which font or font feature is needed for some font shape and then builts the NFSS-structure on-the-fly. But it can fail, that's why there are options like `BoldFont` which help fontspec.

You still can create fd-files and use them. E.g. the default lmr-fonts are setup in the `eu1lmr.fd` / `tulmr.fd`.

Comment: Perhaps add that `.fd` files are required for cases where there are different font files for different optical sizes (only Latin Modern that I know of).

Comment: @JosephWright: I don't think that they are required, you could use the fontspec option SizeFeatures.

Comment: Thanks (+1). Regarding `.fd` files, `fontspec` will look for them?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes but you probably wouldn't want to do that in every document if using a font with optical sizes available

Comment: @cjorssen: LaTeX will look for "EncodingFamily.fd" if it doesn't know a font.

Comment: @JosephWright: No ;-). But you could also write a "MyXY.fontspec" and so use only fontspec syntax if you prefer it.

Comment: So are the `.fd` file and the `.fontspec` file the same approach with different syntax? Should one prefer the whole `fontspec` ecosystem?

Comment: That's your decision. The advantage of fd-files is that they can be used without fontspec, but you need to learn the syntax -- fontspec options are probably easier for most people. Also you can't use \addfontfeature with fonts loaded by fd-files.