# Change bold math font with mathspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, mathspec

I want to change the math font by `mathspec`. My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmathsfont(Latin,Greek){Eu-bx.ttf}
\setmathsfont(Digits){EU-bz.ttf}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EU-bz.ttf}
\begin{document}
Hello world!

$a+b=2^t$

$\mathbf{abcd}$
\end{document}
```

However the math font hasn't got bold. So I'd like another font called `EU-hx.ttf` to be used for bold math(that is to say, make LaTeX call this font when it meets `\mathbf{}`). How can I do this?

Comment: Is there a reason for using `mathspec` instead of `unicode-math`? Put differently, are you willing to switch to `unicode-math`? Separately, are the font files `Eu-bx.ttf` and `EU-bz.ttf` available online?

Comment: @Mico Because I haven't known the `unicode-math` package. I'll try switching to it. Is it better?

Comment: @youthdoo The differences are discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118244/what-is-the-difference-between-unicode-math-and-mathspec, but the short version is: `unicode-math` uses OpenType math fonts, while `mathspec` uses OpenType text fonts and tries to combine them withother fonts to make them usable in math. If you have a proper math font then `unicode-math` will give much better results, if you try to use text fonts for math then things will get complicated anyway but mathspec might be a reasonable option.

Comment: Question: Are letters and digits all you need from your document's math font? Any `\sum`, `\int`, or `\frac` terms? Any other math-y symbols, such as `\in`, `\subset`, `\leq`, `\cap`, or `\cup`? If you answer some (or all) of these questions with "yes", you should probably start looking around for an opentype math font that's visually compatible with the text font of your choice.

Comment: @Mico I only need to change the letters, digits.