# font designating integer, rational, real, or complex

Tags: math-mode

what is the font used to designate Z (ring of integers), Q (field of rationals), R (field of reals) and C (field of complex)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Merlin has given you the answer down below - but just to give you a bit of info, this style is referred to as "blackboard bold" and not everybody is a fan. The idea behind blackboard bold is that it's how bold letters can be written on a blackboard. In other words, these are sometimes still (and originally always were) just plain old bold letters and when they were written on a blackboard, they were double-struck to mimic the emboldening. So you can (and people do) just use bold as well. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$\mathbb{R}$` for this and include the amssymb package: `\usepackage{amssymb}`.
Also consider this: [Real number symbol (UTF-8: ℝ) in XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104274/real-number-symbol-utf-8-%E2%84%9D-in-xetex)

Answer (score 1):

Old style books (and Bourbaki up to nowadays) used simply

```
   \mathbf Z, \mathbf Q, \mathbf R, \mathbf C
```

As explained by @Au101, the use of blackboardbold faces has its origin in the quasi-impossibility to write boldface  letters on a blackboard, and their conventional replacement with double-struck letters