# Number sets symbols in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

[image]

Does anybody know how I can get exactly that symbol for the set of real numbers in LaTeX?

Additional image:
[image]

In this picture you have the symbol for the set of integers, real numbers and complex numbers. I think this must be a package.

Comment: \mathbb{R}  (amsfonts packagage)

Comment: Does the symbol have to be rendered in Arial (or some other sans-serif font that features a "straight-legged" uppercase-R letter)?

Comment: Could be a diplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104274/

Comment: No it's not a duplicate

Comment: @DavidCarlisle gave you the package you need to load (`\usepackage{amsfonts}` or alternatively you can try `\usepackage{amssymb}`). If ℝ is `\mathbb{R}`, ℂ is `\mathbb{C}` and I'm sure you can work out the rest yourself. Sure the font is different in this work, in fact the ℂ is quite clearly crudely double struck by having a C and then another C shortly afterwards (which I suppose you could do by hand in LaTeX if you really wanted to), but are you then asking how to get that exact font?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for that exact font.

Comment: The letter `C` looks just awful. Are you sure you want to replicate such a disaster?

Comment: that isn't a font it's just over-printed letters which is what we used to do before blackboard bold fonts came available, surely you don't want to do that now?

Comment: BTW: what book is it from? It looks as a Polish book to algebra, written using LaTeX methods from the previous century... And I know at last one person, who still writes in such manner. :-)

Comment: Reminds me of the time a professor sent me some LaTeX and it turns out he used something like `I\!\!\!R`and `Z\!\!Z`.

Answer (score 40):

An exact font for the symbols does not exist, because the symbols are composed from letters. The image clearly shows, that especially the Z- and C-symbols are poor man's versions of the symbol. All the three symbols are generated by two shifted letters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\CC}{%
  \textsf{C\kern-1ex C}%
}
\newcommand*{\RR}{%
  \textsf{I\kern-.3ex R}%
}
\newcommand*{\ZZ}{%
  \textsf{Z\kern-1ex Z}%
}
\begin{document}
\textbf{a)} nad \ZZ,
\textbf{b)} nad \RR,
\textbf{c)} nad \CC
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Alternatives for comparison

### Package `amssymb`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\textbf{a)} nad $\mathbb{Z}$,
\textbf{b)} nad $\mathbb{R}$,
\textbf{c)} nad $\mathbb{C}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \mathbb of package amssymb]

### Package `fourier`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
\textbf{a)} nad $\mathbb{Z}$,
\textbf{b)} nad $\mathbb{R}$,
\textbf{c)} nad $\mathbb{C}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result fourier]

### Package `dsfont`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\begin{document}
\textbf{a)} nad $\mathds{Z}$,
\textbf{b)} nad $\mathds{R}$,
\textbf{c)} nad $\mathds{C}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \mathds of package dsfont]

### Sans serif version of `dsfont`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sans]{dsfont}
\begin{document}
\textbf{a)} nad $\mathds{Z}$,
\textbf{b)} nad $\mathds{R}$,
\textbf{c)} nad $\mathds{C}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result dsfont, sans serif]

### Font "Segoe UI Symbol" (LuaTeX/XeTeX)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\SymbolFont{Segoe UI Symbol}
\begin{document}
\textbf{a)} nad {\SymbolFont\symbol{"2124}},
\textbf{b)} nad {\SymbolFont\symbol{"211D}},
\textbf{c)} nad {\SymbolFont\symbol{"2102}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result for Segoe UI Symbol]

### Font "FreeSans" (LuaTeX/XeTeX)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\SymbolFont{FreeSans}
\begin{document}
\textbf{a)} nad {\SymbolFont\symbol{"2124}},
\textbf{b)} nad {\SymbolFont\symbol{"211D}},
\textbf{c)} nad {\SymbolFont\symbol{"2102}}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result for FreeSans]

Comment: Heiko, you have also a sans serif with `dsfont`, if I remember correctly you activate them with `sans` option.

Answer (score 13):

Yet one more to the collection:

**Font "Bbold"**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbold}
\begin{document}
\textbf{a)} nad $\mathbb{Z}$,
\textbf{b)} nad $\mathbb{R}$,
\textbf{c)} nad $\mathbb{C}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe]

Note: In text mode you can use also  `{\bbfamily Z}`